# PHP time calculation producing unreliable outcome

Tags: php, time

I have a script which uses the following logic to see if a stored UNIX timestamp is older than 14 hours:

```
if ($data['today'][$city]['max']['imported'] < (time() - 50400)) { 
    // bad stuff
} else {
    // good stuff
}
```

In the six or so days this has been running every 10 minutes (via CRON job), it's gone to "bad stuff" four times, at seemingly random times of day, for no apparent reason. The value of $data['today'][$city]['max']['imported'] is derived from an XML file which is converted into array form each time the script runs. There are 8 cities, & this calculation is in a loop that iterates over them (hence $city). The XML is stored in a text file.

Last time it happened I had implemented saving of the $data['today'][$city]['max']['imported'] value and it was definitely valid (i.e. 10 mins old).

Is there something obvious I've missed?

Also, if anyone knows of a more reliable way to check if a timestamp is older than 14 hours I'd be grateful - this has to work in PHP 5.1.something, hence no access to the DateTime class.

Comment: Where does `$data['today'][$city]['max']['imported']` come from?

Comment: So it works for whole world but not you and your conclusion is it's not your fault? Good luck in IT :)

Comment: An XML file which is converted into array form each time the script runs. There are 8 cities, & this calculation is in a loop that iterates over them (hence $city).

Comment: If it comes down to question of whether the bug is in library code or in your code, it's going to be in your code 99% of the time.

Comment: My apologies for the bad phrasing guys. I have no doubt the fault is 99.9% likely to be mine, just don't know what.

Comment: @da5id Is there anything funky going on with timezones?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');

Comment: Just log the values inside `bad stuff` and debug from there

Comment: ...actually, the server would is in 'Australia/Sydney'.

Comment: why not use the db time\date functions

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @Sam Thanks, I am. The stored timestamp is definitely valid. What I'm not logging (but seemingly should) is the value of time() at the, er, time. I'll do that, but this error doesn't happen very often & I can't force it.

Comment: No database. The XML is stored in a text file - will clarify question.

Comment: @da5id can you give me an example of what `$data['today'][$city]['max']['imported']` returns .. now?

Comment: Last it went wrong, it was: 1362614407. Now it's: 1362622629.

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace that timestamp calculation with `diff()` from PHP's `DateTime` class. As you have it, the calculation will not give correct results two times per year: when daylight savings time causes the addition or subtraction of an hour.

Other than that, the issue you're experiencing is most likely to do with your `$data['today'][$city]['max']['imported']` being an incorrect value, or timestamp discrepancies due to timezone differences between your server, and wherever the `imported` timestamp is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, I so wish I could do that, but the production server belongs to client & it's running PHP 5.1.something - pre the good stuff :(

Comment: Good point about Daylight Savings, cheers. The same server stores the timestamp as does the comparison, so I don't think it's that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code at all. the code should function perfectly with no problem. The only weakness I see is the `$city` value that is retrieved from your xml file. You said you only have 8 cities in your xml, do you have a default value if somebody from a different city?

one way to solve your problem is to check what your `$data['today'][$city]['max']['imported']` value before using the if statement

something like this can help, checking if you are getting 10 characters in your string :

```
if (strlen($data['today'][$city]['max']['imported'] == 10) { 
//your code here
}
```